# General methods to show $g(x) \geq f(x)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Suppose you have a compact interval $[a,b]$ and a function which is positive and bounded in this interval, $0 \leq f(x) \leq f_{max} < \infty$. How would you show that another function $g(x)$, which is also bounded and positive in the same interval, is everywhere greater than $f(x)$?

This is a fairly general question and I'm interested in any techniques that may be available to show such a thing. Some methods that I have already thought of using are to show:

1. $g(x)-f(x) \geq 0$, $\forall x$
2. $[g(x)-f(x)]_{min} \geq 0$

Comment: For continuous functions $f,g\,$, if $f(x) = g(x)$ has no solutions on $[a,b]\,$, then either $f \lt g$ or $f \gt g$ on the entire interval.

Comment: Thank you @dxiv for your answer. Do you have any ideas on how to show $f<g$ or $f>g$ without the methods already proposed in this post and answers?

Comment: How would you prove that a number which you know nothing about is strictly positive (or not) *in general*? The question is too broad, and you can't expect completely generic answers.

Comment: The same way the methods that I presented in my post work for general functions.. It is meant to be broad because I'm just brainstorming ideas on how to prove inequalities for continuous bounded functions.

Answer (score 2):

A fairly common technique, if $f,g$ are differentiable, is to show that $f(a) \le g(a)$ and that $f'(x) \le g'(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.  Then $f(x) \le g(x)$ follows by the mean value theorem.

You can extend this: if $f,g$ are $n$ times differentiable, you can show that $f(a) = g(a)$, $f'(a) = g'(a)$, ..., $f^{(n-1)}(a) \le g^{(n-1)}(a)$, and that $f^{(n)}(x) \le g^{(n)}(x)$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Thank you @Nate-Eldredge ! This technique seems fairly conservative as it relies on extra structure of $f$ and $g$. Do you know any other ways to show the inequality without this extra requirement?